# How can I use the rows of a table as the name of a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I want create new tables with this row names, so the every row will be a different table.

First I selected the data what I needed and put in my table

```
declare @cDeviceID  nvarchar(max)
declare @cAllin nvarchar(max)
set @cAllin = ''
create table d14 (Techem_Device varchar(max))

declare DeviceID cursor dynamic
for
select DeviceID from DEVICES where Manufacture='Socomec'

open DeviceID
fetch first from DeviceID into @cDeviceID

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    set @cAllin = 'T' + @cDeviceID
    insert into D14 select @cAllin 
    fetch next from DeviceID into @cDeviceID

END
Close DeviceID
deallocate DeviceID
```

After that I tried create the query:

```
exec ('create table' + @cAllin + '(Datum datetime, Device_0, Device_1)')
```

But that created the error message:

> Unknown object type 'tableT25882' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER
>   statement.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: Seems like you're on very thin ice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed space between `table` keyword and table name itself here:

```
exec ('create table' + @cAllin + '(Datum datetime, Device_0, Device_1)')
```

Also it is better to wrap table name into square brackets for the case when table name will be reserved keyword:

```
exec ('create table [' + @cAllin + '] (Datum datetime, Device_0, Device_1)')
```

Also notice you haven't specified column type for `Device_0, Device_1` columns.

Answer (score 0):

It was missed spece as mentioned in Andy answer but I want to propose to you another solution. You can avoid `CURSOR` using this:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE [' + DeviceID + '] (Datum DATETIME, Device_0, Device_1)
GO
'
FROM DEVICES
WHERE Manufacture='Socomec'
```

Use *Result to Text* option in SSMS. It generates script which allows you to create tables based on DEVICES table values.

Remember to specify data types for all columns.